Suppes–Lemmon-Style $\Diamond$-Introduction and -Elimination Rules for Modal Logics?
I'm trying to find natural-deduction introduction and elimination rules for $\Diamond$ (possibility) in popular modal logics (e.g., K, T, S4, and S5) in the style of Suppes and Lemmon, where on each line of the proof you have a dependency set, a line number, a formula, and a citation, e.g.,
$\begin{array}{1111}&\{1\} &1. &P &\text{Premise}\\
&\{1\} &2. &P \lor Q &\text{1 $\lor$I} \\
\end{array}$
Satre (1972) is the closest thing I've found; he gives a bunch of rules for introducing or eliminating $\Box$ (necessity) in the abovementioned logics (and many more besides), but unfortunately doesn't give any for $\Diamond$. An earlier poster over on Philosophy StackExchange suggested $\Diamond$-introduction and -elimination rules for S5, but formulated them in terms of subproofs—which aren't a thing in the Suppes and Lemmon style—and only gave them for S5.
If there's a textbook that gives such rules, that'd be ideal, especially if it has accompanying exercises to practice using them, but it's fine if someone's just able to formulate them themselves.

There are two major texts on the formulation of natural deduction rules for modal logics. One is Garson's Modal Logic for Philosophers. The other is Simpson's The Proof Theory and Semantics of Intuitionistic Modal Logic (Ch. 4).
Of the two, I find Simpson's to be the most directly useful. The gist is that he defines his introduction and elimination rules to work for system K, and then allows for relation statements $xRy$ to be assumed to permit the uses of these rules. He then adds rules strictly to those modal relations to allow systems D, M/T, 4, B, and 5. Garson's appears to take classical logic as a given, even though Gentzen's original natural deduction was for intuitionistic logic.
